# r shiny hide/show all checked checkboxes

Tags: r, checkbox, shiny

I would like to simply hide or show all checked checkboxes in R shiny the following code can be used as a reference :

```
ui <- shinyUI({
  library(shiny)
  library(shinyjs)

  shinyUI(fluidPage(

    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),

    actionButton(inputId = "fishButton",  label = "Fish"),
    checkboxInput(inputId = "hide_show_checked", label = "Hide/Show all checked checkbozes"),
    hidden(
      checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "Check1",
                         label   = h4("Fish:"), 
                         choices = c("Bass", "Shark", "Tuna"))
    )
  ))
})


serv <- shinyServer({
  library(shiny)
  library(shinyjs)

  shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(input$fishButton, {
      toggle("Check1")
    })
  })
})

shinyApp(ui,serv)
```

I am sure I would need to add an observe event in the server part, but I am tending to overthink this, by creating duplicate checkbox  groups and displaying the checkbox group 1 if checked and displaying checkbox group 2 if not checked... This would result in a lot of duplication in my actual code (I have more than 1000 checkbox groups)

Thanks!!

Comment: So if you check "Bass" in check1, you want to be able to hide it? Does it all need to be in a `checkboxGroupInput`?

Comment: Yes exactly! If I check "Bass" and "Tuna" and then I check  the "Hide/Show..." checkbox, I would like to only see "Shark". It has to be checkboxGroupInput yes...

Comment: They make specific UI elements where if you select something the option goes away (see `selectizeInput`). Are you open to that option?

Comment: If it works, then I am most definitely open to it. I will have a look thanks!

Comment: check https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.2/updateCheckboxGroupInput.html

Comment: @A.Suliman Thanks for the link, but this is pretty much what I was trying to avoid... You see this is duplicating each checkbox group - I will end up with way too many checkboxes, which won't be a problem from a coding point of view, but it will be inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
ui <- fluidPage(

    checkboxInput(inputId = "hide_show_checked", label = "Hide/Show all checked checkbozes"),
    checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "Check1",
                 label   = h4("Fish:"), 
                 choices = c("Bass", "Shark", "Tuna")),
    verbatimTextOutput("value")

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

   output$value <- renderPrint({ input$Check1})

   observe({

      if(input$hide_show_checked) {

             #x <- ifelse(data %in% c("Bass", "Shark", "Tuna"), data, "NA")

             data <- isolate(input$Check1)
             y <- c("Bass", "Shark", "Tuna")
             x <- y[!y %in% data]
   #y[-match(data,y)] OR setdiff(data,y)

  updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "Check1",label = paste("Checkboxgroup label", length(x)),choices = x,selected = x)
} else {
  updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "Check1",label = "Checkboxgroup label", choices = c("Bass", "Shark", "Tuna"),selected = NULL)
 }
   })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I hope it help ;)

Comment: Hi, indeed it does not do what I was expecting. However I think this is a good starting point for me. Thanks! :)

Comment: Hi, unfortunately this does not help. Since you are "overwriting" the choices - perhaps this is the only way, but the ShinyApp I am building is quite complex and by overwriting the choices, it will affect another part of the app. That is why I would prefer to only hide the checked boxes, instead of overwrite them with new ones - of course only if this is possible...